# Angular:Why NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA does not work for attribute?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testbed

I'm writing my first Angular tests and having a problem here. I'm testing a component, which has a custom attribute in it

```
<ng-container *isGranted="admin">
...
</ng-container>
```

[Official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing#no_errors_schema) says

> The NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA tells the Angular compiler to ignore unrecognized
>   elements and attributes.

So I added the following to my `TestBed` config:

```
schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
```

But still, I'm getting an error:

> Property binding isGranted not used by any directive on an
>   embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled
>   correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations

Where am I wrong? I do not want to test how `isGranted` behaves, I just want to check that a correct value was assigned to it.

Comment: At first, it looks like your `isGranted`-directive is not added to your TestBed configurations. Try adding it as a declaration or provider.

Comment: @John when I adding this to declaration the compiler trying to initialize the attribute and throws an error that service (the one that is used inside the attribute) is missing

Comment: I am not sure if that is the reason, but did you try something like this?     `TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [isGranted]
    });` You also need to provide the services you use in the isGranted-directive inside your TestBed configuration as well.

Comment: I do not want to provide the service, that's the point. Anyway, this is how the official doc says

Comment: Have you tried to provide the services as well? Maybe use a Mock-service if the service in itself is not applicable for testing. Even though you want to isolate testing, if the isGranted-directive is using some services in order for it to work, you at least need to provide a mock if I am not mistaken.

Comment: I do believe that if I mock the service behavior this will break the concept of unit testing, because if I change the service in future, this particular test stay green, because service is mocked.

Comment: NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA - ignores custom component, while you are using ng-container which is not custom :)

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat good point, but changing ng-container to div did not change anything

Comment: @LuninRoman because of directive, so my point is error schema is to ignore custom components but not directives

Comment: On a second thought, since you are not testing the isGranted directive, you can mock that one instead? Something like this? `declarations: [{provide: isGranted, useValue: {}}]`

Comment: @John no its directive and not provider :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using directive, while NO_ERROR_SCHEMA is to ignore custom components. See [github](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6ece7db37a267b20d129aba9f0275c59d7ec0fa6/packages/compiler/src/template_parser/template_parser.ts#L731) when error is thrown with proper exception saying that you need to include directives

```
Property binding ${prop.name} not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations".
```

Comment: @LuninRoman Docs are correct :) No_schema ignores component inputs, outputs but not directives

Comment: isn't directive is the same as attribute is my case?

Comment: @LuninRoman you are using structural directive https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives

Comment: if you would use normal directive with attribute then it will ignore it :)

Comment: Its a bit confusing

Comment: what does it mean - normal directive?